# Unable to understand the base cases for this recurrence relation: DPn = DPn-1 + DPn-3 + DPn-4

Tags: recurrence-relations, integer-partitions, dynamic-programming

I read the following [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/tutorial/)
*Sub-problem*: DPn be the number of ways to write N as the sum of 1, 3, and 4.
*Finding recurrence*: Consider one possible solution, n = x1 + x2 + ... xn. If the last number is 1, the sum of the remaining numbers should be n - 1. So, number of sums that end with 1 is equal to DPn-1.. Take other cases into account where the last number is 3 and 4. The final recurrence would be:

DPn = DPn-1 + DPn-3 + DPn-4.

Base cases: DP0 = DP1 = DP2 = 1, and DP3 = 2.

**My Problem** - I do not at all understand the base cases, I did get the recurrence relation though. Am
not getting as to what `DP0 = DP1 = DP2 = 1` really mean here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many ways can you write each of $0,1,2,3$ as a sum of $1,3,4$?

- For $n=0$, the empty sum is the only way.
- For $n=1$, $1$ is the only way.
- For $n=2$, $1 + 1$ is the only way.
- For $n=3$, $3$ and $1 + 1 + 1$ are the only two ways.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I understood 3 more recurrences after reading your excellent explanation, accept my gratitude !